# Errors on Json deserialize

Tags: java, android, json, gson

i'm trying deserialize my object, but I can not get no error!

I'm using gson on android to read json file.

**My deserialize**

this is my request class, i using a rest server.

```
     public Object getListaSeguradoras(String _codPais, String _tipoPesquisa)
{

     try {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Config.WS_PATH);
        post.setHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        post.addHeader("Client-Application","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");


        //Make object in JSON format
        JSONObject dato = new JSONObject();

       dato.put("CodPais", _codPais); 
       dato.put("TipoPesquisa", _tipoPesquisa);

       StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(dato.toString());
       post.setEntity(entity);

       HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post);
       String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

       Gson gson = new Gson();

       Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<SeguradoraLista>>(){}.getType();
       Collection<SeguradoraLista> ListaSeguradoras = gson.fromJson(respStr, collectionType);

       return ListaSeguradoras;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**My object:**

This is my getter and setter

```
    public class SeguradoraLista{

    public String SeguradoraId;
    public String Nome;

    public String getSeguradoraId() {  
        return this.SeguradoraId;  
    }  

    public String getNome() {  
        return this.Nome;  
    }  

    public void setSeguradoraId ( String SeguradoraId) {  
        this.SeguradoraId = SeguradoraId;  
    } 

    public void setNome ( String Nome) {  
        this.Nome = Nome;  
    } 
}
```

**My json:**

this is the json string on my string respStr

```
     [{"SeguradoraId":"19","Nome":"AIG Europe"},
{"SeguradoraId":"25","Nome":"AIOI Insurance Co. Of Europe"},
{"SeguradoraId":"28","Nome":"Aktiv Forsikring A/S"},
{"SeguradoraId":"160","Nome":"Enter Forsikring AS"},
{"SeguradoraId":"167","Nome":"Euro Insurances Ltd."},
{"SeguradoraId":"189","Nome":"Försäkrings-AB Volvia"},
{"SeguradoraId":"219","Nome":"Gjensidige NOR Forsikring"},
{"SeguradoraId":"245","Nome":"If Skadeforsikring NUF"},
{"SeguradoraId":"265","Nome":"Jernbanepersonalets Forsikring Gjensiding"},
{"SeguradoraId":"271","Nome":"KLP Skadeforsikring AS"},
{"SeguradoraId":"284","Nome":"Landbruksforsikring"},
{"SeguradoraId":"309","Nome":"Lloyd's v/Vital Skade AS"},
{"SeguradoraId":"459","Nome":"SpareBank 1 Skadeforsikring AS"},
{"SeguradoraId":"472","Nome":"Tennant Forsikring nuf"},
{"SeguradoraId":"473","Nome":"Terra Skadeforsikring AS"},
{"SeguradoraId":"494","Nome":"Trygg-Hansa Forsikring Nuf"},
{"SeguradoraId":"517","Nome":"Vesta Skadeforsikring A/S"},
{"SeguradoraId":"536","Nome":"Zürich Forsikring"}]
```

what I'm doing wrong? I can't make this direct deserealizing?

Comment: What is `SeguradoraLista`?

Comment: So sorry, Is my object, i fixe my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an array of `SeguradoraLista` objects.

So just create a `TypeToken` of type `List<SeguradoraLista>`

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<SeguradoraLista>>() {}.getType();
List<SeguradoraLista> ListaSeguradoras = gson.fromJson(respStr, collectionType);
```

Actually, `Collection<SeguradoraLista>` would work as well.

Comment: Sorry i fix my post, SeguradoraLista is my object

Comment: I try using list and not work! Temporarily I use this(THOR):  'ArrayList<String> roomTypes = new ArrayList<String>();

           JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(respStr);

           for(int i =0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
               roomTypes.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Nome"));
           }'

Comment: @kaub0st3r If the JSON you get from the HTTP response is what you've shown us, then what I have above will work. Actually, what you have in your question should work just fine as well.

Comment: @kaub0st3r Also, if something doesn't work, **always** tell us how and why it doesn't work. Do you get an exception? Does it behave differently then you'd expect? What are your expectations?

Comment: No, i can catch any expetion, when i make debug i don't catch nothing, simply jumps to the end!!!  my catch is `} catch (JsonParseException eJson) {
      eJson.printStackTrace();
         return null;
     } catch(Exception  ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
         return null;
     }`

Comment: My import to **Type** is **import java.lang.reflect.Type;**

Comment: @kaub0st3r I don't understand. Your code doesn't throw any exceptions? Then it must work properly and `return ListaSeguradoras;`

Comment: No, i can't catch exceptions. Not ask me why, but o put this declaration `Collection<SeguradoraLista> ListaSeguradoras;` out of function and works!!! I'm new on Java, you know why this appends?

Comment: @kaub0st3r Again, it's not very clear what you are doing. If you want, edit your question with the new code and I might be able to help.